# How to configure two emails in a spring 2.5 web application using xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to create two mail configuration in my spring 2.5 web application.I have already one configuration working well .Is it possible to add one more?
I could see this facility in latest spring .But i cant implement in spring 2.5. Can anybody help me.
below is my current configuration.

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        
        <property name="host" value="${mailer.smtpHost}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${mailer.smtpPort}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mailer.userId}"/> 
        <property name="password" value="${mailer.password}"/>  
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property> 
    </bean>


  <bean id="bulkMailer" class="com.akshay.utils.BulkMailer">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/> 
    </bean>
```

BulkMailer.java

```
 public class BulkMailer implements Mailer {
        
        private JavaMailSender mailSender;//this is working
        private JavaMailSender secondMailSender;//not working
    
        private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BulkMailer2.class);
    
    }
```

when i try to inject second mail config like
`private JavaMailSender mailSender2;` Exception throwing

I could't create any second bean like
<bean id="mailSender2"
for second mail configuration

Can anybody know how to do xml based configuration for this?

WHAT I TRIED IS SHOWN BELOW

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${mailer.smtpHost}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${mailer.smtpPort}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mailer.userId}"/> 
        <property name="password" value="${mailer.password}"/>  
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property> 
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="secondMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${mailer.smtpHost}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${mailer.smtpPort}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mailer.userId}"/> 
        <property name="password" value="${mailer.password}"/>  
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property> 
    </bean>



<bean id="bulkMailer" class="com.akshay.utils.BulkMailer2">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    <property name="secondMailSender" ref="secondMailSender"/>
</bean>
```

below is the Exception i got

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'secondMailSender' of bean class [com.greytip.common.utils.BulkMailer2]: Bean property 'secondMailSender' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it work. Just create an additional config for the mail sender and inject it.

Comment: I tried that .while doing that i got an Exeption like cannot see that new bean Id that i make. I named beanId as "mailSender2"

Comment: please show what you tried. It should just work so you must be not doing what you think you are doing.

Comment: Please find my updated question above. I think bean name mailSender is internally defined in spring. when i create second bean secondMailSender caused this
error. How can i resolve this?

Comment: The error message indicates you don't have a setter method. A field isn't a property without a getter or setter. IN this case a writeable property requires a setter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could able to configure second mail in my application.
Below shows the config and code

```
<bean id="bulkMailer" class="com.akshay.utils.BulkMailer2">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
        <property name="secondMailSender" ref="secondMailSender"/>
    </bean>



 public class BulkMailer2 implements Mailer {
        private JavaMailSender mailSender;
        private JavaMailSender secondMailSender;
    
        public void setSecondMailSender(JavaMailSender secondMailSender) {
            this.secondMailSender = secondMailSender;
        }
    }
```